# Set datasource at runtime ActiveReports 10

Tags: vb.net, datasource, activereports

I try to set datasource at runtime in my report of Activereports 10.

i have this code in the script :

'''

Sub ActiveReport_ReportStart

```
Dim connectionString = “Data Source=PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Contratti;Integrated    Security=True”

Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
con.Open()

Dim _strSQL As String = "Select id , cod from customers"

Dim _cm As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(_strSQL, con)

Dim _dt As New DataTable
Dim _da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(_cm)
_da.Fill(_dt)
_dt.TableName = "customers"
Me.DataSource = _dt
```

End Sub

'''

I have the error :

localhost:52620

Error: Report Script Compile Error on line 50 :

‘DataSource’ non è un membro di ‘Script.ReportScript’

What can i control ?

i’d like load my datatable at runtime and set it to the report .

Thank you

Comment: solvedi used RPT.DataSource = _dt

Answer (score 0):

When using vb script I think you must use "rpt." instead of "Me."

Also, including your connectionString  within the ActiveReport scripts is a bad idea. RPX files are not secure.  See [AR2pro](https://help.grapecity.com/activereports/webhelp/Legacy/AR2Pro/AR2Pro_start.htm).

Using AddCode and AddNamedItem  methods the scripts can be cut down to simply

```
Sub OnDataInitialize
    set rpt.datsource.recordset = vbcode.getrset
End Sub
```